# Make the activity below opaque

Tags: android

I have an activity and once I click a button, another activity starts. This new activity doesen't occupy all the window, so a part from the activity below it's visible.
I'm looking for a way to set opacity to the part that the new activity doesen't ocuppy.
**In styles, I have used WindowIsTranslucent="true", but this makes the activity transparent instead of opaque**

Thank you in advance.

To reduce de size of the activity I have used:

```
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .95), (int) (height * .8));
```

The result has to be something like the image.
[image]

Comment: you can use PopupWindow..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by setting the background color for the specified activity which you want to be in less opaque. I meant the over all parent layout of the activity. you use this color code to achieve this **#cb000000**.

Hope this is helpful:)